# How do I override PySerial's "__del__" method in Python?

Tags: python, serial-port, overriding, pyserial

I have a simple Python script set up to send Characters to a device on COM3.
(This is running on Windows XP)
The device receives the Characters fine, but when the script ends, or I call

```
ser.close()      #ser is an instance of the `serial` method `Serial`
```

It sets the DTR Line on the serial port High, Resetting my Device.

Perplexed by this, I poked around in the PySerial Documentation (http://pyserial.sourceforge.net/) and found that the Module has a `__del__` method, which calls the `ser.close()` function when the Serial instance is deleted.

Is there anyway to Override this `__del__` method?

*(I would prefer to not have to disconnect the Reset Line of my device from the DTR line)*

Below is the basic code I am using:

```
import serial
ser = serial.Serial()
ser.port = 2      #actually COM3
ser.baudrate = 9600
ser.open()
ser.write("Hello")
ser.close()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, go ahead and override it. You can either create a subclass of `Serial` and specify a do-nothing `__del__()` method and use the subclass instead of `Serial`, or delete that method from the actual `Serial` class (monkey-patching) using the `del` statement. The former method is preferred but the second may be necessary if code you don't have any control over is using the serial port.  Be sure the `__del__()` method doesn't do anything else important before overriding it, of course.

Subclassing:

```
import serial

class mySerial(serial.Serial):
    def __del__(self):
        pass

ser = mySerial()
# rest of script the same
```

Monkey-patching:

```
import serial

del serial.Serial.__del__
```

If you have Python source for this module (i.e. it is not written in C), a third approach would be to create your own copy of it and just edit it not to do that.  (You can also do this for C modules, but getting it running is a bit more difficult if you don't have C expertise.)

Of course, changing the `__del__()` method to not call `ser.close()` isn't going to help much in the code you give, since you're calling `ser.close()` yourself.  :-)

Comment: I just tried the Monkey Patching, and it threw an Error.
Subclassing did not throw an error, but the device is still receiving a DTR signal, even with the last `ser.close` removed.

Comment: I just commented out the `set_DTR` function, and all is working now.
Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried something like this?

```
MySerial = serial.Serial

def dummy_del(obj):
    pass

MySerial.__del__ = dummy_del

ser = MySerial()
```